# Spring security intercept-url with combined multiple roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am quite new to Spring and meet some difficulties configuring Spring security rules.

Here are my rules :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/administration/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATION" />
<intercept-url pattern="/programmation/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATION, ROLE_SAISIE, ROLE_CONSULTATION" />
<intercept-url pattern="/programmation/validate" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATION', 'ROLE_SAISIE', 'ROLE_CONSULTATION') and hasAnyRole('ROLE_NATIONAL', 'ROLE_REGIONAL')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/restitution/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATION, ROLE_RESTITUTION" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATION, ROLE_SAISIE, ROLE_CONSULTATION, ROLE_RESTITUTION" />
```

I just added the third one, and when starting the server, it yield a quite strange Exception from my point of view :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATION', 'ROLE_CONSULTATION') and hasAnyRole('ROLE_NATIONAL', 'ROLE_REGIONAL'), 'ROLE_SAISIE']
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:156) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 49 more
```

As you can see, it come from

```
hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATION', 'ROLE_SAISIE', 'ROLE_CONSULTATION') and hasAnyRole('ROLE_NATIONAL', 'ROLE_REGIONAL')
```

to

```
hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATION', 'ROLE_CONSULTATION') and hasAnyRole('ROLE_NATIONAL', 'ROLE_REGIONAL'), 'ROLE_SAISIE'
```

I suppose there is a kind of bad interraction between the rules, but I can't figure out what happens exactly.

Comment: You are mixing [expression-based](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web) and non-expression syntax for the `access` attribute. Add the `use-expressions` attribute and use `hasRole` throughout.

Comment: I can't find the 'throughout' part in the documentation, but indeed, it seems to be the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: I mean "throughout" your configuration (i.e. you can't mix them). From that link, if you set `use-expressions='true'`, "Spring Security will then expect the access attributes of the <intercept-url> elements to contain Spring EL expressions. The expressions should evaluate to a boolean, defining whether access should be allowed or not."

Answer (score 2):

Try to set for parent's tag `<http>` attribute `use-expressions="true"`, should be something like this:

```
<http use-expressions="true"> 
     <intercept-url pattern="/administration/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATION" />
     <intercept-url pattern="/programmation/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATION, ROLE_SAISIE,        ROLE_CONSULTATION" />
....
```